# Show that a specific matrix difference is positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I need to show that for two specific matrices $A$ and $B$ the difference
$$A-(I-B)A(I-B)^\prime$$
is positive semidefinite.
How do I start this?

Comment: What do you know about the matrices $A$ and $B$?  Is $B$ a projection?

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite, take $M = A^{1/2}$. Your difference is positive semidefinite if and only if we have 
$$
\|Mx\| \geq \|M(I-B)'x\|
$$
for all vectors $x$.

Comment: Yes, the claim is not true without further restrictions on the matrix $B$. For $1 \times 1$ matrices $A=1, B=3$, it turns out that the above expression gives $-3$ and is negative.

Comment: I know that I can rewrite my problem in a more cumbersome expression like
$$C-(I-CR^\prime(RCR^\prime)^{-1}R)C(I-R^\prime(RCR^\prime)^{-1}RC)$$
for some positive semidefinite matrix $C$ and another (nonsquare) matrix $R$ and show that this matrix is positive semidefinite instead

Comment: And yes, $B$ is a projection
@Omnomnomnom